# How to create asymmetric errorbars without triggering broadcast error?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, array-broadcasting, errorbar

I'm trying to plot some asymmetric error bars using seaborn. I can't understand why I'm getting a `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,1) (2,3)`

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

truth = np.array([0.15725964, 0.15611989, 0.15820897])
hpd = np.array([[0.00310974, 0.01833195],
                        [0.00546891, 0.017973  ],
                        [0.00687474, 0.01628064]])
median = np.array([[0.15517015],[0.12985473],[0.12510344]])

with sns.plotting_context('notebook', font_scale=1.2):

    fig, axmatrix = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(16,8))
    for ax in axmatrix.flatten():
        ax.set_aspect('equal')

    def plot_hpd_err(truth, hpd, median):        
        err = np.absolute(np.transpose(hpd - median@np.ones((1,2))))
            
        return ax.errorbar(truth[:,np.newaxis], median, yerr=err)
 
plot_hpd_err(truth, hpd, median)
```

- If I comment out the yerr=err, the code runs fine.
- The shapes of `truth[:,np.newaxis]`, `median`, and `err` are (3,1); (3,1); and (2,3) respectively.
- I formatted `err` to be (2,N) shape because that's what the [`axes.errorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar.html) documentation tells me to do
- when I transpose `truth[:, np.newaxis]` and `hpd` to match `err`'s shape, it throws an error.

Ultimately, I want three data points with their respective asymmetric errorbars, but I'm currently not able to get an ErrorbarContainer object without any errors (yes, the plots are currently blank...)

Answer (score 0):

The size of `truth` and `hpd` must be (N,); it can**not** be (N, 1).
Therefore, the code should read

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

truth = np.array([0.15725964, 0.15611989, 0.15820897])
hpd = np.array([[0.00310974, 0.01833195],
                        [0.00546891, 0.017973  ],
                        [0.00687474, 0.01628064]])
median = np.array([0.15517015, 0.12985473, 0.12510344])

with sns.plotting_context('notebook', font_scale=1.2):

    fig, axmatrix = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(16,8))
    for ax in axmatrix.flatten():
        ax.set_aspect('equal')

    def plot_hpd_err(truth, hpd, median):        
        err = np.absolute(np.transpose(hpd - (median[:, np.newaxis])@np.ones((1,2))))
            
        return ax.errorbar(truth, median, yerr=err)
 
plot_hpd_err(truth, hpd, median)
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62525717/20039030) for helping me figure this out.

Comment: alternatively, you can use `np.squeeze()` if you have a (N,1) array and want to make it (N,)